# Key event in savefig in python. How to do it?

Tags: python, image-processing, keyboard, matplotlib

I'm try to understand python doing some codes. I want to select a part of a open image with zoom and save the selected part.
 Right now i'm trying to quickly save the open and zoom image by pressing a key. For explain better, i need to fire a function savefig() by pressing a keyboard key.

I tried to use urwid module :

```
import urwid
import PIL
import Image
im=Image.Open("fig.tif")
imshow(im) 

def save(input):

    if input in ('s'):
        savefig("fig2.png")
```

And I used uinput as well to try do it the same thing:

```
import uinput 
import PIL
import Image 

def main():
    capabilities = {uinput.EV_KEY: (uinput.KEY_S)}
    device = uinput.Device(name="python-uinput-keyboard", capabilities=capabilities)
    if device.emit(uinput.EV_KEY, uinput.KEY_S, 1):
        savefig("sat.png")

im=Image.open("fig.tif")
imshow(im)
```

And i have the same result in this 2 codes, this error message appeared:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in call
return self.func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 312, in key_press
FigureCanvasBase.key_press_event(self, key, guiEvent=event)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1143, in key_press_event
self.callbacks.process(s, event)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 163, in process func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1703, in key_press self.canvas.toolbar.save_figure(self.canvas.toolbar)
TypeError: save_figure() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

It's strang because i never open Tkinter. Please help´me with that, How do i save the zoom image with a key event?

I'm sorry by my ignorance in python, i'm very new at this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't explicitly say it, but it appears that you're using matplotlib to do this.

I can't say for certain from what you've posted, but I'd guess that what's happening is that `s` is already bound to "save figure" for a matplotlib figure. (And by default, matplotlib uses a Tk-based backend, thus the Tk error.)

There's no need to use the `urwid` module. Matplotlib has hooks to do things like this, and you're going to need to disconnect some of those hooks to do what you need.

As a simple, stand-alone example to reproduce your problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def save(event):
    if event.key == 's':
        print 'Saved figure'
        event.canvas.figure.savefig('temp.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', save)
plt.show()
```

Notice that the figure will be saved, but you'll also get a pop-up file selection dialogue to save the figure *again*.

You can avoid this by either: a) using a different key (something not in [the list here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/navigation_toolbar.html#navigation-keyboard-shortcuts)) or b) temporarily disabling matplotlib's key binding of `'s'` to save.

It's pretty easy to temporarily disable it with the appropriate [matplotlibrc setting](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# Disable the 's' interactive keybinding
mpl.rcParams['keymap.save'] = ''

def save(event):
    if event.key == 's':
        print 'Saved figure'
        event.canvas.figure.savefig('temp.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', save)
plt.show()
```